# Integrating with respecting to a probability measure defined by $P=\lambda\cdot f$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ and $P=\lambda\cdot f$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=1_{(0,1)}(x)$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is the uniform density. Let $X,Y$ be
two real random variables defined by $X(x)=2x$, $Y(x)=2x1_{(0,1)}(x)$

"**Question**": Is it true tha $X = Y$ $P-$a.s?

The question is straight forward to me but getting there is tough:
$$P(X\neq Y)=P((-\infty,0)\cup [1,\infty))=\int_{(-\infty,0)\cup [1,\infty)}1_{(0,1)}(x)d\lambda(x) = 0$$

**My actual question**: Why does the integral appear as such. If $P=\lambda\cdot f$, then why would the integral not become (excuse my lack of knowledge with integrating over a weighted measure)

$$P(X\neq Y)=P((-\infty,0)\cup [1,\infty))\\=\int_{(-\infty,0)\cup [1,\infty)}d(\lambda(x)1_{(0,1)}(x)) \\=\int_{(-\infty,0)\cup [1,\infty)}d\lambda(x)d1_{(0,1)}(x)$$

Comment: your question doesn't make any sense. You are asking for something like "why the color blue is not yellow?" Or in other words, why do you think that the integral must be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $P=\lambda\cdot f$ is a bit uncommon to me but I suspect that it must be interpreted as follows.

$P$ is a probability measure on measurable space $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}\right)$
defined by: $$P\left(B\right)=\int1_{B}fd\lambda\tag1$$where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$.

Some other notations for the LHS are:

- $\int_Bf(x)d\lambda$
- $\int1_B(x)f(x)\lambda(dx)$
- $\int1_B(x)f(x)dx$

Note that $\left\{ X\neq Y\right\} =\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid X\left(x\right)\neq Y\left(x\right)\right\} =\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid2x\neq2x1_{\left(0,1\right)}\left(x\right)\right\} =\left(-\infty,0\right)\cup\left[1,\infty\right)$
so that according to $(1)$: $$P\left(X\neq Y\right)=P\left(\left(-\infty,0\right)\cup\left[1,\infty\right)\right)=\int1_{\left(-\infty,0\right)\cup\left[1,\infty\right)}fd\lambda=0$$Here the RHS is $0$ simply because the integrand is the zero-function.

What you call "my actual question" might arise from misunderstanding of or unfamiliarity with (notation of) integrals. This is confirmed by uncommon notations like  $d\lambda(x)d1_{(0,1)}(x)$. I have never seen that before hence have no proper answer to that actual question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @drhab. By $(1)$ this makes complete sense. The notation of $P=f\cdot \lambda$ was confusing to me as it is my first probability course.

Comment: You are very welcome. I am glad that things are clear for you now.